# Django - combining forms for related models

Tags: django-forms

Is there a common method/best practice/any means for combining forms that span multiple related models?

I want to create/edit model objects along with other, related model objects on the same page. Basically, being able to create/edit one model instance and another set of model instances related by a foreign key.

Not a great explanation, I know.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) 
    number = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to be able to create/edit a person, along with all their associated phone numbers using a single form/page.

I've done this before using [this nested form](http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/) example, but it seems quite hackish.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Use formsets, specifically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: inlineformset_factory gives a formset that would allow me to edit PhoneNumbers, but not the associated Person. If I bundled a PersonForm along with the PhoneNumberFormset (from the factory) together into the context, could I still modify them both on the same page, with save() working properly for them both?

Comment: Yes, pass both the form and the formset to the page, then put them in the same form, and in your view, check form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() then do form.save() and formset.save().  If there is any overlap in the names of the fields, you might have to add a prefix argument when you define the form.  I'll look around my OS code for an example.

Comment: It should be noted, for all intents and purposes, this is how django.contrib.admin handles this situation.